# Failing to send REST requests after i added spring security via a Vaadin video

Tags: spring, rest, authentication, postman, vaadin

I added security to my Vaadin application exactly as described by this official video of vaadin
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dZuy1v9isXE&ab_channel=vaadinofficial

After adding it, I added authorization to my Rest request (Im sending them via Postman. In the authorization  tab of the request i chose "Basic Auth" and added the username and password), and tried to send it, but got back a very weird body in the 200 response, i added it as a picture:
[picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GESeL.png)

Comment: Your REST endpoint is also handled via Vaadin now, so this is not what you wish. Make sure that your rest endpoints are not routed via vaadin

Comment: how can i make sure that my rest endpoints are not routed via vaadin

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking
a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Have you tried moving vaadin out of the root (`vaadin.urlMapping`) or is this not an option?

Comment: @cfrick how can i do it?

Comment: You are supposed to put `vaadin.urlMapping` in your `application.properties`.

Comment: @TatuLund Can you refer me to an example so I will try to implement it on my project?

Comment: I added to my application.yml the following line:
 vaadin:
  urlMapping: /ui/*

and now my Vaadin UI is at http://localhost:8501/ui

But when I send REST requests to http://localhost:8501/mockers (Which worked before adding vaadin security) it still gives back the same vaadin response I mentioned earlier (I added authorization to my Rest request).